# Weird Class Behaviour

Tags: c++, class

```
  class Blades
   {
   public:
       Blades(int test):speed(test){}

       void Blades_draw()
       {
           al_draw_filled_circle(100, 100, 5, al_map_rgb(26, 116, 217));
       }
    private:
        int speed;
    };
```

I have made lots of classes kinda similar to this, I have a main.cpp where everything is implemented. All other class works fine, this one is problematic even though its so simple. The class is not done and the elements are there for test reasons.But still when I try to declare a variable at main.cpp like the following

```
Blades blade(50);
```

It acts weird for some reason, in the state when I'm still typing it `Blades blade(`, nothing shows up, while other class have the intellisense thing. And when I do put a value and enclose it with parenthesis, it doesnt complain. But when I try to access the class later in desire to access some elements `blade.Blades_draw();`, when I reach the dot part, it doesnt give me suggestion, and a red crooked underline shows up saying that blade is undefined. My head is about to blow up and i need to finish this project before school tommorow.

Comment: First, it would be nice if you mentioned the editor you are using; second, `Blades_draw()` looks like you are trying to write C in C++.

Comment: @Griwes although the class is very sparse how does it look like C in C++?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010, and its just a testing functino because I have to retract all my steps looking for mistakes.

Comment: How is this class different from the other classes?
Have you checked to make sure your main.cpp has included the proper header file for this class?

Comment: I did, there are actually 3 other classes in this objects.h header. I declared #include "objects.h" and all other 3 classes work fine except this one. I"m going nuts.

Comment: yes there is. Now I fixed my problem, what I did is I deleted a uneccessary destructor from the class on top of this. Still doesnt makes sense why there is a correlation.

Comment: @111111, I mean putting class name in function name. It was that weird kind of namespacing in C: namespace_struct_function_name(), I guess you've seen it before.

Comment: @Griwes, oh right fair enough, but not a big deal though.

Comment: wow, well thanks guys, sorry for the rage below.

Answer (score 5):

Your class is called "Blades", not "Blade."

Comment: Compiling the mistake should give a pretty comprehensible error if you take the time to look back once.

Comment: @JoeyArnoldAndres - Stack Overflow is a Q&A system not a forum.